# Complex Excel Formula in Pandas

Tags: pandas, formulas

Excel Formulas I am trying to replicate in pandas:
[Click here to download workbook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37919918/BTLogic.xls)
* Look at columns D, E and F

- `entsig` and `exsig` are manual and can be changed.  In real life they would be derived from the value of another column or a comparison of two other columns
- `ent` = 1 if `entsig previous` = 1 and `in` = 0
- `in` = 1 if `ent previous` = 1 or (`in previous` = 1 and `ex` = 0)
- `ex` = 1 if `exsig previous` = 1 and `in previous` = 1
- so either `ent`, `in`, or `ex` will always be = 1 but never more than one of them

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0], 
     [0,1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0], 
     [0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0], 
     [0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0], 
     [1,1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0]], 
    columns=['entsig', 'exsig','ent', 'in', 'ex'])

for i in df.index:
    df['ent'][(df.entsig.shift(1)==1) & (df['ent'].shift(1) == 0) & (df['in'].shift(1) == 0)]=1
    df['ex'][(df.exsig.shift(1)==1) & (df['in'].shift(1)==1)]=1
    df['in'][(df.ent.shift(1)==1) | ((df['in'].shift(1)==1) & (df['ex']==0))]=1

for j in df.index:    
    df['ent'][df['in'] == 1]=0
    df['in'][df['ex']==1]=0
    df['ex'][df['ex'].shift(1)==1]=0

df
```

results in

```
    entsig  exsig  ent  in  ex
0        0      0    0   0   0
1        1      0    0   0   0
2        1      0    1   0   0
3        1      0    0   1   0
4        0      0    0   1   0
5        0      1    0   1   0
6        0      1    0   0   1
7        1      0    0   0   0
8        1      0    1   0   0
9        0      0    0   1   0
10       0      0    0   1   0
11       0      0    0   1   0
12       0      1    0   1   0
13       0      1    0   0   1
14       0      1    0   0   0
15       0      0    0   0   0
16       0      0    0   0   0
17       1      0    0   0   0
18       1      0    1   0   0
19       1      0    0   1   0
20       1      1    0   1   0
21       0      1    0   0   1
22       0      1    0   0   0
23       0      1    0   0   0
```

## Question

- How can I make this code faster? It runs slow because it's a loop but I have not been able to come up with a solution that does not use loops. Any ideas or comments are appreciated.

Comment: Just remove the `for` loops they seem to be redundant to me

Comment: Also you are performing what is known as chain indexing which may operate on a copy rather than a view, see the docs:http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy basically you should use `ix` or `loc` instead

Comment: If I remove the for loops, the answer will be wrong. Thanks for the chain indexing tip.

Comment: Well your last for loop does look redundant to me

Comment: I just ran your code with and without the for loops and the results are the same

Comment: OK, I didn't appreciate the effect of the for loop but these lines `df['ent'][df['in'] == 1]=0` and `df['in'][df['ex']==1]=0` can be moved out of the for loop and this will shave a little time off

Comment: "so either ent, in, or ex will **always** be = 1" does not seem to be true. Should that rule be "so either ent, in, or ex **may** be = 1"?

Comment: Can we assume that a group of ones in `entsig` will always be followed by a one in `exsig`?

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume every group of 1's in `entsig` is followed by at least one 1 in
`exsig`, then you could compute `ent`, `ex` and `in` like this:

```
def ent_in_ex(df):
    entsig_mask = (df['entsig'].diff().shift(1) == 1)
    exsig_mask = (df['exsig'].diff().shift(1) == 1)
    df.loc[entsig_mask, 'ent'] = 1
    df.loc[exsig_mask, 'ex'] = 1
    df['in'] = df['ent'].shift(1).cumsum().subtract(df['ex'].cumsum(), fill_value=0)
    return df
```

---

If we can make this assumption, then `ent_in_ex` is significantly faster:

```
In [5]: %timeit orig(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 185 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit ent_in_ex(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.23 ms per loop

In [95]: orig(df).equals(ent_in_ex(df))
Out[95]: True
```

where `orig` is the original code:

```
def orig(df):
    for i in df.index:
        df['ent'][(df.entsig.shift(1)==1) & (df['ent'].shift(1) == 0) & (df['in'].shift(1) == 0)]=1
        df['ex'][(df.exsig.shift(1)==1) & (df['in'].shift(1)==1)]=1
        df['in'][(df.ent.shift(1)==1) | ((df['in'].shift(1)==1) & (df['ex']==0))]=1

    for j in df.index:    
        df['ent'][df['in'] == 1]=0
        df['in'][df['ex']==1]=0
        df['ex'][df['ex'].shift(1)==1]=0
    return df
```